# sfml window that displays shapes crashing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, crash, window, sfml

So I made this "game" as a joke in visual studio 2013 using c++, and it ran fine as of two weeks ago. I copied it onto a flash drive and set up visual studio on my laptop with the same configurations as the computer I made it on so I could show it to people at a later date. Today, I complied it on my laptop to show it to my friend, but it crashed, giving me a stack overflow error that never occurred on the other computer. I have absolutely no idea where it's being generated, either, as the call stack only shows that sfml-system-d-2.dll or something was called constantly. I have a loop for it to draw a ton of random shapes all over the place, but that ran fine on the other computer, which was also less powerful than the one I'm using right now. I'll keep looking at it to see if I can find the specific place in my code where it happens.

```
font.loadFromFile("times.ttf");
warning.setFont(font);
warning.setColor(sf::Color(rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255,alpha));
warning.setString("Warning: If epileptic, do not look at screen");
warning.setCharacterSize(30);
warning.setPosition(0, 80);
```

Apparently there's some problem with the times.ttf file, because it shows up as NULL, even though I have it in the same folder as my program and code. 
Anyway, the program finally crashes when I actually display all the stuff to the window.

Comment: My answer was deleted so... anyways, if you can provide some code that would be awesome.

Comment: @Canvas added code in the question. Not sure why it would cause crashing, but it opened a file with what I guess was for error checking, so maybe it is. I really don't know at this point :/

Comment: for me straight up I'm going to say it is the font. have you got times.ttf in the project? Your font variable maybe getting disposed of at the end of your function call so your sf::Text warning's font will be null. Take a look at your font and see what is happening.